# Windows 10 loudness equalization release time keeps resetting

Tags: windows-10, audio

I turn on loudness equalization and then go to settings change the release time to short and click okay/apply and then I checked the settings again and the release time has changed back to where it was before I changed it I can't figure out what keeps resetting it